# C# - check if column in CSV exists before assigning it to datatable

Tags: c#

I have this:

```
 var productDetailsFromFile = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                          select new ProductDetails
                                          {
                                              ItemNumber = row.Field<string>("Item Number"),
                                              Cost = row.Field<string>("Cost").ToDecimal(),//custom method .ToDecimal
                                              WHQtyList = new List<int>()
                                              {
                                                  row.Field<string>("foo").ToInteger(),//custom method .ToInteger
                                                  row.Field<string>("bar").ToInteger(),
                                                  row.Field<string>("foo2").ToInteger(),
                                              }
                                          }).ToList();
```

It reads the info from a .csv file. What I am trying to achieve is an elegant way of checking if Fields "foo", "bar" or "foo2".

Right now the issue is that if from the CSV file I remove one of the columns, column not in datatable error pops up. I can't get this to work for 2 hours now.

What I am essentially seeking is - how to check if a column exists as I use it to initialize the list, or if the column doesn't exist the default value to be 0 for each row, where it doesn't exist.

Comment: are you using any libraries to work with your CSV? if not - maybe check out https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/

Comment: I think this has to do more with DataTables than processing the CSV. I am trying to avoid processing the CSV, and directly work with DataTables. If I can't figure it out, I will just go with the CSV directly.

Comment: okay, I presume you have looked at `DataTable.Columns`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.columns?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @SvetoslavAntonov To check for existence of a specific column you can just do the following: 
`if(dt.Columns.Contains("foo"))`

Answer (score 0):

I did it through a method. I was wondering if there was a way to do it faster without having to add additional lines of code or make the additional lines of code less than what they are now.

```
int ContainsColumn (string columnName, DataTable table, DataRow row)
            {
                DataColumnCollection columns = table.Columns;
                if (columns.Contains(columnName))
                {
                    return int.Parse(row.Field<string>(columnName));
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
```